# wordpress перевелся частично

Tags: wordpress, хостинг, локализация, админка, перевод

День добрый всем! 
Проблема: ставлю русифицированный wordpress на 2 разных хостинга, на одном все нормально, а на втором половина админки не перевелась. Файлы переводов присутствуют и идентичны как для WP так и для плагинов.
Поддержка хостинга, на котором беда, грешит на настройки WP, которые такие же как и на рабочем хостинге.
Спасайте, братцы!))

[image: скрин админки]

Comment: Всё очень информативно :-)
А по существу пробуйте проверять пути

Comment: Ставил ВП из панелей хостинга? Зайди в обновления и переустанови/обнови и ВП.